# Play Framework tmp disk full with class files

Tags: java, linux, configuration, playframework-1.x

In production mode play (version 1.2.6) writes compiled class files into the 
`app/tmp/bytecode` and `app/tmp/classes` folder.

It seems like those files are never cleaned up and not recycled per request. 
After a few hours runtime the disk of my ec2-box is full with gigabytes of class files.

What am I supposed to do? Is there a config option I missed?

Do I have to clean the tmp folder myself with a cron job? If so, is it safe to delete the class files while the system is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself.
A template was rendered from a string and not from a file. On each request the template was assigned a new random name.

And all the random named class files were stored in the temp directory and play does not clean the temp directory.